# How would I embed an imgur post into my site using html

Tags: html, css, embed, imgur

imgur's built in embed isn't working. It gives me nothing on my site when I try embedding the imgur vids using their built in methods.

The link leads to videos, which is what I suspect is causing the issues.

```
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/AutqEKM"  ><a href="//imgur.com/a/AutqEKM">lego robotics robot built</a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

is what imgur provides with the embed tag.

Comment: Have you tried an https: before the // ?

Comment: sadly that doesn't work. It just gives me a text that links to the post instead

Comment: Do imgur's terms and conditions allow direct embedding with a video?